# Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.activemq.web.AjaxServlet

Tags: java, activemq-classic, apache-tomee

I am trying to configure the ActiveMQ in the TomEE and use the ActiveMQ webconsole. After downloading ActiveMQ release 15.16.3 I imported the project to Eclipse and converted it to Maven. After builing the war file by Maven and deploying it to `apache-tomee-plus-8.0.9\webapps`, I am getting in the Tomee console the following error

```
'Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.activemq.web.AjaxServlet'
```

TomEE has inbox alle needed files:
[image]

I have used the same web.xml as in the 'apache-activemq-5.16.3\webapps-demo\demo\WEB-INF\web.xml'

*Error:*

```
:45:10.902 INFORMATION [main] org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance.<init> openejb.home = C:\APPS\apache-tomee-plus-8.0.9
07-Mar-2022 13:45:10.902 INFORMATION [main] org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance.<init> openejb.base = C:\APPS\apache-tomee-plus-8.0.9
07-Mar-2022 13:45:10.904 INFORMATION [main] org.apache.openejb.cdi.CdiBuilder.initializeOWB Created new singletonService org.apache.openejb.cdi.ThreadSingletonServiceImpl@46944ca9
07-Mar-2022 13:45:10.906 INFORMATION [main] org.apache.openejb.cdi.CdiBuilder.initializeOWB Succeeded in installing singleton service
07-Mar-2022 13:45:10.927 INFORMATION [main] org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory.init TomEE configuration file is 'C:\APPS\apache-tomee-plus-8.0.9\conf\tomee.xml'
07-Mar-2022 13:45:10.957 INFORMATION [main] org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory.configureService Configuring Service(id=Tomcat Security Service, type=SecurityService, provider-id=Tomcat Security Service)
07-Mar-2022 13:45:10.959 INFORMATION [main] org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory.configureService Configuring Service(id=Default Transaction Manager, type=TransactionManager, provider-id=Default Transaction Manager)
07-Mar-2022 13:45:10.961 INFORMATION [main] org.apache.openejb.util.OptionsLog.info Using 'openejb.deployments.classpath=false'
07-Mar-2022 13:45:10.976 INFORMATION [main] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createRecipe Creating TransactionManager(id=Default Transaction Manager)
07-Mar-2022 13:45:11.010 INFORMATION [main] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createRecipe Creating SecurityService(id=Tomcat Security Service)
07-Mar-2022 13:45:11.070 INFORMATION [main] org.apache.openejb.server.ServiceManager.initServer Creating ServerService(id=cxf)
07-Mar-2022 13:45:11.191 INFORMATION [main] org.apache.openejb.server.ServiceManager.initServer Creating ServerService(id=cxf-rs)
07-Mar-2022 13:45:11.210 INFORMATION [main] org.apache.openejb.server.SimpleServiceManager.start   ** Bound Services **
07-Mar-2022 13:45:11.210 INFORMATION [main] org.apache.openejb.server.SimpleServiceManager.printRow   NAME                 IP              PORT
07-Mar-2022 13:45:11.210 INFORMATION [main] org.apache.openejb.server.SimpleServiceManager.start -------
07-Mar-2022 13:45:11.210 INFORMATION [main] org.apache.openejb.server.SimpleServiceManager.start Ready!
07-Mar-2022 13:45:11.210 INFORMATION [main] jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Server initialization in [920] milliseconds
07-Mar-2022 13:45:11.258 INFORMATION [main] org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBNamingContextListener.bindResource Importing a Tomcat Resource with id 'jms/queue/MyQueue' of type 'org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue'.
07-Mar-2022 13:45:11.258 INFORMATION [main] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createRecipe Creating Resource(id=jms/queue/MyQueue)
07-Mar-2022 13:45:11.270 INFORMATION [main] org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBNamingContextListener.bindResource Importing a Tomcat Resource with id 'jms/ConnectionFactory' of type 'org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory'.
07-Mar-2022 13:45:11.270 INFORMATION [main] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createRecipe Creating Resource(id=jms/ConnectionFactory)
07-Mar-2022 13:45:11.275 INFORMATION [main] org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBNamingContextListener.bindResource Importing a Tomcat Resource with id 'UserDatabase' of type 'org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase'.
07-Mar-2022 13:45:11.275 INFORMATION [main] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createRecipe Creating Resource(id=UserDatabase)
07-Mar-2022 13:45:11.278 INFORMATION [main] org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBNamingContextListener.bindResource Importing a Tomcat Resource with id 'jms/topic/MyTopic' of type 'org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQTopic'.
07-Mar-2022 13:45:11.278 INFORMATION [main] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createRecipe Creating Resource(id=jms/topic/MyTopic)
07-Mar-2022 13:45:11.280 INFORMATION [main] jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Starting service [Catalina]
07-Mar-2022 13:45:11.280 INFORMATION [main] jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.56]
07-Mar-2022 13:45:11.292 INFORMATION [main] jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Deploying web application archive [C:\APPS\apache-tomee-plus-8.0.9\webapps\apache-activemq-5.16.3-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war]
07-Mar-2022 13:45:11.297 INFORMATION [main] org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.init ------------------------- localhost -> /apache-activemq-5.16.3-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
07-Mar-2022 13:45:11.299 INFORMATION [main] org.apache.openejb.util.JarExtractor.extract Extracting jar: C:\APPS\apache-tomee-plus-8.0.9\webapps\apache-activemq-5.16.3-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
07-Mar-2022 13:45:11.374 INFORMATION [main] org.apache.openejb.util.JarExtractor.extract Extracted path: C:\APPS\apache-tomee-plus-8.0.9\webapps\apache-activemq-5.16.3-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
07-Mar-2022 13:45:11.421 INFORMATION [main] java.util.ArrayList.forEach Name = test_schema Ignoring unknown property: value of "jdbc/test_schema" for "global" property
07-Mar-2022 13:45:11.502 WARNUNG [main] org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal jms/ConnectionFactory resource was defined in both tomcat and tomee so removing tomcat one
07-Mar-2022 13:45:11.504 INFORMATION [main] org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory.configureApplication Configuring enterprise application: C:\APPS\apache-tomee-plus-8.0.9\webapps\apache-activemq-5.16.3-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
07-Mar-2022 13:45:11.524 [main] org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal Unable to deploy collapsed ear in war StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/apache-activemq-5.16.3-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: Unable to load servlet class: org.apache.activemq.web.AjaxServlet: org.apache.activemq.web.AjaxServlet
                at org.apache.openejb.config.AnnotationDeployer$ProcessAnnotatedBeans.deploy(AnnotationDeployer.java:2299)
                at org.apache.openejb.config.AnnotationDeployer$ProcessAnnotatedBeans.deploy(AnnotationDeployer.java:2018)
                at org.apache.openejb.config.AnnotationDeployer.deploy(AnnotationDeployer.java:384)
                at org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory$Chain.deploy(ConfigurationFactory.java:420)
                at org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory.configureApplication(ConfigurationFactory.java:1033)
                at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1318)
                at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.configureStart(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1162)
                at org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.lifecycleEvent(GlobalListenerSupport.java:134)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5135)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:726)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:698)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:696)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1024)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1911)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:123)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:825)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:475)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1618)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:319)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:946)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:835)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:263)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:432)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:927)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772)
                at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
                at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
                at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:345)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:476)
        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.activemq.web.AjaxServlet
                at org.apache.openejb.core.TempClassLoader.loadClass(TempClassLoader.java:186)
                at org.apache.openejb.core.TempClassLoader.loadClass(TempClassLoader.java:83)
                at org.apache.openejb.config.AnnotationDeployer$ProcessAnnotatedBeans.deploy(AnnotationDeployer.java:2292)
                ... 48 more
```

**New added Information:**

I have unziped the war file and there is no classes in the WEB-INFO/classes directory. I got the "BUILD SECCUSS" message by Maven.